# efficiently get joined and not joined data of a dataframe against other dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have two dataframes lets say A and B. They have different schemas.

I want to get records from dataframe A which joins with B on a key and the records which didn't get joined, I want those as well.

Can this be done in a single query?
Since going over the same data twice will reduce the performance. The DataFrame A is much bigger in size than B. 
Dataframe B's size will be around 50Gb-100gb.
Hence I can't broadcast B in that case.

I am okay with getting a single Dataframe C as a result, which can have a partition column "Joined" with values "Yes" or "No", signifying whether the data in A got joined or not with B.

What in case if A has duplicates? and I don't want them.
I was thinking that I'll do a recudeByKey later on the C dataframe. Any suggestions around that?

I am using hive tables to store the Data in ORC file format on HDFS.
Writing code in scala.

Comment: I want to get records only from dataframe A which joins with B on a key and the records which didn't get joined, I want those as well(these are records from Dataframe A itself).
I want rows from only A not B. I want rows from A which joined with B and the ones which did not join with B marked with a column if they did match or not with B.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you just need to do a left-outer join:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

val A = sc.parallelize(List(("id1", 1234),("id1", 1234),("id3", 5678))).toDF("id1", "number")
val B = sc.parallelize(List(("id1", "Hello"),("id2", "world"))).toDF("id2", "text")

val joined = udf((id: String) => id match {
  case null => "No"
  case _ => "Yes"
})

val C = A
  .distinct
  .join(B, 'id1 === 'id2, "left_outer")
  .withColumn("joined",joined('id2))
  .drop('id2)
  .drop('text)
```

This will yield a dataframe `C:[id1: string, number: int, joined: string]` that looks like this:

```
[id1,1234,Yes]
[id3,5678,No]
```

Note that I have added a `distinct` to filter out duplicates in `A` and that the last column in `C` refers to wether or not is was joined.

> EDIT: Following remark from OP, I have added the `drop` lines to remove the columns from B.

Comment: I don't need the columns from B. The schema I'm interested is in
A's schema, "joined"  that's it.

Comment: @grv if my answer is what you were looking for could you then please mark it as accepted answer? Otherwise, please clarify any problems you have with the answer.

Comment: I needed one more help.
What if I want records in Table A which are not in Table B based on a key.
Other way to look at it is except clause  on a key and not the entire record.